# configuration error message on google play store when uploading new APK

Tags: android

i am uploading new APK file on google play store but when i upload it shows an message like

```
This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s): Version 3 is not served to any device configuration: all devices that might receive version 3 would receive version 4.
```

how can i resolve these error

Comment: Compare  your manifest for both versions...

Comment: @PankajKumar my first manifest version 1.3 and now latest version 1.4

Comment: What I am saying is to compare your manifest, not only version name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play store checks version with **versionCode** not **versionName**. And versionCode only allows `integer`. So, there cannot be 1.3 nor 1.4 as a VersionCode. see [document](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html).

You can change `android:versionCode="5"` in `androidmanifest.xml` and check whether error message is shown or not.

If you use `build.gradle` file in the project, remove the value at the `androidmanifest.xml` and only set it in `build.gradle` file as below.

```
defaultConfig {
    versionCode 5 // <- this line to set.
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
```

If you want to know what uploaded versionCode is, you can click uploaded package list. The apk information popup will show up.